# Why does it say there is a problem with my print statements?

Tags: python, syntax

1. For some reason, it says there is a syntax error with my print statements. Why?
2. Can I call the function inside Step_1()?
3. Did I use the sys.exit() correctly

I have no clue what to do. Only the first print statement works.

```
#Imports#
import turtle

def Draw():

 #Theres supposed to be a turtle drawing here#

def Step_1():

    #Show "My Favorite Food"
    print ("My Favorite Food: 1- Description; 2- Picture; 3-Exit")

def Step_2():

    #Prompt Input#
    UserChoise = str(input("Please choose an option (1,2,3):")
    if UserChoise == 1:
        print ("The History of this food.")
    elif UserChoise == 2:
        return Draw()
    elif UserChoise == 3:
        print ("Good Bye.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print ("Invalid Input")



Step_1()
Step_2()
```

I just want it to print those statements. Also if the UserChoise is equal to 3, it should exit the program

Comment: Use Python 3 and `input()` already returns a string.

Comment: Also, if you could [edit] your question to include the error you are seeing, it would help people find the issue quicker

Comment: Yeah, that would be helpful. This is my first time posting a question so sorry about that.

Comment: Feel free to read over the [help] for more info on "good questions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a parenthesis at the end of:

```
UserChoise = str(input("Please choose an option (1,2,3):")
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you, that fixed the problems. However, I ran into another problem: when I input a choice (1,2,3), it always says "Invalid Input"

Comment: @TAHMIDULAMBIA `UserChoise` will never equal `1` , for example. You want `int(input("choose an option"))`

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: Now my last problem seems to be exiting the program when UserChoise is equal to 3. It says: 'sys' is not defined

Comment: Use `import sys`